# How can I reverse an array using map?

Tags: javascript

I get the error that "array" is undefined when running this code. In my solution, I need to use map() to reverse my array.

```
var names = ["Lars", "Jan", "Peter","Bo", "Frederik","Anna"];

 var newArray = array.slice(0).reverse().map(function(name){
        return name;
    });

console.log(backwards(newArray));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to provide the array `names` instead of using `array`, which is undefined

```js
var names = ["Lars", "Jan", "Peter", "Bo", "Frederik", "Anna"]
var newArray = names.slice(0).reverse().map(function(name) {
  return name;
});
console.log(newArray)
```

also most of the functions do nothing in this case. You really only need `names.reverse()` as mentioned in the comment.

If you do want to use `map()`, it's a bit more complicated, and not the right function to use for reversal.

---

**update**

> How can I convert it to a function???

well `reverse` already is a function, but if you want to use map and create a new function using es6 style convention, (`const foo = () => {})`) you could use map as an iterater, as [Nina Scholz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1447675/nina-scholz) did in her answer.

```js
var names = ["Lars", "Jan", "Peter", "Bo", "Frederik", "Anna"]
const backwards = (arr) => arr.map((_, i) => arr[arr.length - i - 1]);

console.log(backwards(names))
console.log(backwards([0, 1, 2]))
```

Comment: How can I convert it to a function???

Comment: please mention that the second part is from me. the first version does not contain a real mapping.

Answer (score 3):

You could map the items with a calculated index.

```js
var names = ["Lars", "Jan", "Peter", "Bo", "Frederik", "Anna"],
    reversed = names.map((_, i, a) => a[a.length - i - 1]);

console.log(reversed);
```

Answer (score 2):

Hmm there is no point in using map it can be simply done on this way

```
var newArray = names.reverse();
```

Comment: i know the reverse, but i have to use map.